# Execution Plan Window is missing. Are results required for execution plans?

Tags: sql-execution-plan, sql-server-2016

I am no longer about to see the tab for execution plans. I am using SSMS 2016 Version 13.0.11000.7

When I hit show estimated Execution plan i get just a messages tab that says

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

When I run a query doing with show actual Execution plan I just get the messages tab showing how many rows are affected. There is again the message about 1 row affected between each select statement.

I am guessing this might have something to do with the code as the code I am trying this on is just truncate table and insert into commands. There are no results. Are results required for Execution plans?

Edit:
This is the Estimated plan for the code I am trying to use
[image: This is the Estimated plan for the code I am trying to use]

This is the Estimated plan for a simple select * from table code
[image: This is the Estimated plan for a simple select * from table code]

Update:
IT made us upgrade back to 2016 SSMS which I was afraid would cause me to have this issue again but it did not happen. I am able to view execution plans just fine.

I think there might have been some code I ran early on learning about Execution plans that changed a setting I could not find. I had tried some Set Showplan commands early that I was not sure what they did. Still unsure why the setting would affect some code and not all code. Either way it all works now.

Comment: Did you ever find the issue?

Comment: I looked through the settings as best I could and found no difference. I have talked with our IT about permissions. It appears to stem from when they upgraded my ssms to 2016. Once they reverted it back to 2012 no issues. Still unsure as to the actual rason for this.

Comment: Thanks for following up, even if the cause wasn't found. -- You should probably remove the accepted answer from my answer though. Someone might figure this out someday!

Comment: Will do. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a tab that says `execution plan` next to the `messages` tab.

[image]

For `truncate table` you would not get an actual execution plan, just a message that says "Command(s) completed successfully.", but you can see it show up in an estimated execution plan:

[image]

For `insert` you will get an execution plan, example of an insert without indexes:

[image]

Comment: Those are the tabs that i used to see but I am no longer seeing the Execution plan tab. I did see one when i tested with just a select * from SmallTable.

Comment: @ChadPortman You are aware that the option to include the actual execution plan is specific to each query window, correct?

Comment: I am aware of this yes and I selected this option prior to running the code. I have done this in the past but today it is no longer working.

Comment: @ChadPortman Have you tried closing ssms and reopening it? Are you using the button on the navbar or Ctrl+M? Try the other one?

Comment: I have tried using the button on the navbar, Crtl+M and selecting the option via the Query menu. I have not tried closing and reopening so I will attempt that now.

Comment: Still having the same issue. I have posted screen shots now.

Comment: I posted pictures of the estimated as the code takes 30 mins to run so it will take a while to get screenshots of that

Comment: @ChadPortman I'm out of guesses now... Maybe try [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer)? or [the add-in for SSMS 2016](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/plan-explorer-add-in-ssms-2016/)?

Comment: Must be a setting somewhere just tried the same thing on a different machine also running ssms 2016 and it worked just fine. I will start comparing settings when i find the problem I will post the answer